# Python - file readline escapes quotes automatically

Tags: python, file, escaping, readline

So I am reading a big SQL file with python, using this obvious line:

```
f = open('file.sql', 'r')
```

but for some reason when I read it with `read`/`readline`/`readlines` it escapes quotes and double quotes, although the file doesn't have them when opened in say, Vim.

This is a sample from the file:

```
'\"George\'s_House\"'
```

turns into:

```
\'\\"George\'s_House\\"\'
```

Does anyone have any idea about this? Could it be an encoding problem?

Thanks

Comment: Chances are the values are fine but you are inspecting them in a way which shows quotes as escaped (`print ("#r" % value)` comes to mind). Show us what *exactly* you do.

Comment: Great catch. I get the normal thing if I use print (I was just using the console). But the thing is that if I use find to search for that string, apart from escaping single quotes, I still have to escape double quotes like: `line.find('\'\\"George\'s_House\\"\'')` instead of `line.find('\'\"George\'s_House\"\'')`

Comment: That's just normal backslash escaping to get literal backslashes.